# How to sync working directory with master directory, when somebody push change to our local system?

Tags: git

desktop1:

```
mkdir gitrepo
cd gitrepo
git init
git config --bool core.bare true
```

laptop:

```
git clone desktop@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/desktop
cd gitrepo
vi readme
add readme
commit readme
git push
```

desktop1: I could not see the files here.

desktop2: I cloned to anoter 3rd system with the same as above command and I can see the file in 3rd system but not in the repository where I pushed.

So, how to update files in destop1 with the local changed files.

Comment: Is your desktop repository a bare repository (without a working directory)? Is your desktop set up as a Git server? This looks like a duplicate question of when you try to push to a non-bare repo.

Comment: How are you able to push things from your laptop to desktop if your desktop isn't running a Git server? Are you using a file transfer protocol? What is the URI that you're using to push with?

Comment: Why not just have a bare repository on your desktop to push to, then have another non-bare clone on the desktop that you use to fetch from the bare repo? You usually want to push to bare repos with Git.

Comment: Exactly. You're not really supposed to push to non-bare repos.

Comment: You can do it that way, or you can just make a new bare repo with `git clone --bare <remote-uri>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can sync up using the command as:

```
git checkout <file_name>
```

If you want to sync up with file in another branch give the command as:

```
git checkout <branch_name> <file_name>
```

If you want to sync any branch with another branch, give the command:

```
git checkout <branch_name>
git merge <branch_name>
```

#### Example:

Let's say I want to update master with branch br1, so command would be:

```
git checkout master
git merge br1
```